# How to establish a PHP debug session using dbgp (Xdebug) and gedit?

Tags: php, laravel, xdebug, gedit

I need to debug my Laravel application and as I searched Xdebug seemed to be the best option out there. Up to now I couldn't setup a session to the debug my app and I'm confused about how to configure the ambient.

So I run my Laravel app with:

```
php artisan serve --port=8001
```

According to my `php --ini`, the conf file for xdebug is:

```
$ php --ini | grep xdebug
/etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini
```

which contains:

```
$ cat /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini 
[xdebug]
zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_autostart=on
xdebug.remote_enable=on
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.idekey=default
```

and to debug it on gedit, I've installed [this plugin](https://github.com/addiks/gedit-dbgp-plugin). And in the text editor settings for dbgp:

[image]

Can anyone explain to me exactly how this protocol works? If I click "start to listen to debug sessions" it tries to open one on port 8001 (not 9000) which is already in use and of course it cannot open and if it's the case that I must start my PHP app in conjunction with Xdebug then how do I setup it to run it with the default Laravel command (`php artisan serve`)?

And, if I click Start debug in Picture related, it opens in the browser with the exact URL `http://127.0.0.1/?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=default` (in port 80)

Comment: No a gedit user ... but: 1) You do not use (no need at all it for local debug) DBGp Proxy (it's a separate software, must be installed separately) .. so do not configure anything for that; 2) Use `9001` port for Xdebug (will avoid conflicts with php-fpm if you happen to have it installed as it uses the same port); 3) Therefore use `9001` in both php.ini and "Port (listening)" fields; 4) May need to use `http://127.0.0.1:8001/` as "URL to call" (since it's served on that port). 5) If still issues -- collect xdebug logs: https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#remote_log

Comment: thanks, that helped a lot